How can I trigger onMessageReceived with FCM message when app is in the background?
I made an Android app which receive FCM messages, and I want the following behavior:

When the app is completely closed: receive a notification in system tray.
When the app is started but it is in the background: receive a notification in system tray and trigger service onMessageReceived so that I can log the message in the UI.
When the app is started and it is in the foreground: trigger only the service onMessageReceived so I can log the message.

So far I tried to send a combined FCM message like this:
message = {
  'message': {
      'token': app_token,
      'android': {
          'priority': 'HIGH',
          'notification': {
              'title': msg_title,
              'body' : msg_body,
              'color': ColorTable[msg_level],
              'channel_id': ChannelTable[msg_level],
              'notification_priority': 'PRIORITY_HIGH'},
          'data': {
              'value1': 'dummy'}
      } 
  }}

And the in the onMessageReceived:
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // Handle the received message here
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    RemoteMessage.Notification NotifMsg = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    if (NotifMsg != null) {
        String msg_text = NotifMsg.getBody();
        Log.d(TAG, "FCM Received: " + msg_text);
        String msg_time = GetNowDateTime();
        String CID = NotifMsg.getChannelId();
        byte colorID = 0;
        if (CID != null) {
            if (CID.equals(MainActivity.channelNormID)) { colorID = 1; }
             else if (CID.equals(MainActivity.channelWarnID)) { colorID = 2; }
             else if (CID.equals(MainActivity.channelCritID)) { colorID = 3; }
        }
        LogMessage(msg_text, msg_time, colorID);
    }
}

But the onMessageReceived is not triggered when the app is started and is in the background... Any ideas ?

Remove the notification object from your json and put it in your data object and create the notification yourself with that data. When you have the notification object in your payload onMessageReceived does not get called in the background

Indeed, but I want to receive notifications in the system tray too, when the app is not running... Did you read the content of the question ?

Yes I did read what you want and I said you have to manually create the notification instead of having FCM do it. Thats the only way to do it

You don't understand... When the app is not running, I cannot create the notification manually.

Why cant you create it? when only sending data in the payload onMessageReceived is called and then you should use NotificationManager

How can onMessageReceived be called when the app process is not running ?

Because Google Play Services is what calls it, granted some device manufacturers do mess with it and prevent it from starting sometimes but there is nothing you can do about that

You need to remove the notification block from the above JSON, then it should work:
message = {
  'message': {
      'token': app_token,
      'android': {
          'priority': 'HIGH',
          'data': {
              'title': msg_title,
              'body' : msg_body,
              'color': ColorTable[msg_level],
              'channel_id': ChannelTable[msg_level],
              'notification_priority': 'PRIORITY_HIGH'}
      } 
  }}


If I remove the notification block, I will no loger receive nitifications when the app is closed...

I don't think so, because 'priority': 'HIGH' will handle this
